# Why does the character Max Arciniega share the same name with the actor of "Krazy-8"?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, there is a character [Max Arciniega](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Arciniega) who was the best friend of Gus.
On the other hand, there is another character in this movie called "[Krazy-8](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Krazy-8)". The thing is, Krazy-8's actor's real name is [Max Arciniega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Arciniega) too.

My question is, is this just a coincidence or does the movie mean anything by this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative source (apparently it is mentioned in an episode of the [Breaking Bad Insider podcast](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/breaking-bad-insider-podcast/id311058181)), but the character was [named after the actor](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Arciniega#Trivia); it's something Vince Gilligan (creator of *Breaking Bad*) likes to do.

There are [more examples of this](https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/hewess/is_guss_max_arciniega_named_after_max_arciniega/fvv2hsf/) in the show:

> The writers occasionally use actor names for characters.
>
> - Janes last name is Margolis, and the actor who plays Hector is Mark Margolis.
> - In BCS, the shoplifter girl that Saul wants to give the scholarship to has the last name Esposito - Giancarlo Esposito plays Gus.
> - And the photographer from the Mesa Verde copyright plot has the last name Bitsui - the last name of the actor who plays Victor.